# Centering div id

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a div id that holds a background image. The image is 1020px wide which is exactly how big I want the div box to be. I want to center it on the page underneath the header, but I don't want the table or any text within it to be centered. I think that I can create div id/class for the tables and other elements within the div id to align them differently, but I still can't get the div id to center. I've tried the text-align: center property but I'm not having any luck.

This is my CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background:url(img/background_texture.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#header img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#content {
    background-image:url(img/ContentBox.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 1020px;
}
```

This is the basic html structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Metra Train Schedule</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

<body>

<div id="header"><img src="img/Header.jpg" /></div>

<div id="content">

    <table>
    </table>

    <table>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the browser preview, you can see what i'm talking about better here.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Margin auto, when used in conjunction with a width that is less than 100% of the screen, will center an element. If you add `margin: 0 auto;` to the css for the #content, it should do the trick:

```
#content {
    ...
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

More info here: http://learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html

Answer (score 3):

`div {text-align:center;}` DOES NOT WORK FOR DIVS. COMMON MISTAKE.

USE THIS INSTEAD:

```
div {width:1020px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}
```

the "auto" forces the margin on each side to be one half of the remaining space in the page by default. This will NOT center anything within the div. It will work perfectly for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` to automatically center the image if you add `display: block` to it.

```
#header img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto; /* shorthand for left, right auto and top,bottom 0
}
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/ogEkENO/1/edit)**

Perhaps you want to wrap all of your body html in a container and style it this way?

```
#container {
  width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/ogEkENO/2/edit)**

Comment: That made everything become left aligned including the header.

Comment: That would center the image, which he has already acomplished with the text-align:center. However, it might not be a bad idea to switch the header css to #header {width: 1020px; margin: 0 auto; }, in order to be consistent in the centering strategy.

Comment: @DiscipleDavid I don't see what you mean... you asked for it not to affect anything else.

Comment: @DiscipleDavid perhaps you're just looking for a container with a set width and `margin: 0 auto`? See my second demo.

Comment: I changed the way I was centering the header, thanks for that. It would be smart to be consistent.

Comment: @DiscipleDavid It is a very common practice to have a main container like this for a website. It doesn't otherwise affect the contents. This very page is using the same concept, but for some reason, the devs set the width and margin on the header and margin separately instead of putting them in a single container. It's fine either way. The probably did that because the html is more semantic that way (but the css becomes redundant)

Comment: all the  block was pulled to the right !!